# Application Initialization on HTTPS

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, iis, web-config, application-pool

I am looking for some guidance on how to warm up my web application after app pool recycle. So far I used standard Powershell warm-up scripts, but due to company policy we might need to find another solution. I found information that Application Initialization should meet my requirements. Unfortunately I wasn't able to make it work so far.

This is how I configured it in my environment:
I have created host header web application with following Public URL: 
https://test.company.com
I have configured bindings to use proper SSL certificate. Everything works fine.
I have measured request time on my default page (https://test.company.com/default.aspx) using Developer Dashboard after app pool recycle. It took approximately 15 seconds.

Then I have configured Application Initialization according to this article:
https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/iis-application-initialisation-sharepoint-2013
In my case I have added following entry to web.config :
[image]

As I read Application Initialization doesn't work for SSL:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2843964/application-initialization-module-fails-when-web-site-requires-ssl
Therefore I have added following rule to the web.config file of my web application:
[image]

SSL Settings are set according to the article:
[image]

Unfortunately when I try to access my default page I get Server Error:
[image]

When I remove rewrite rule from web.config everything starts working fine (unfortunately without any performance improvement). Additionally I don't see any traffic in Task Manager after app pool recycle. As I understand it should send fake request if everything is configured fine.

My question is: what I did wrong and how can I fix it? Moreover do you know what kind of improvement should I notice after successful deployment (it is possible to go down to 5sec on response time)?

I would be very grateful for any advice in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried using Application Initialization but if you are getting 500 errors, there should be event logs or IIS logs that should give you the exact error on what is happening.

I believe a more simpler solution if you have access to the SharePoint IIS configurations is to:

- Set **Start Mode** to "**Always Running**" - to prevent app pool shut down during inactivity
- Set **Preload Enabled** to **True** - this should load all the DLLs and so on into memory after each time the AppPool recycles.

There are other ways to accomplish this and all this has already been answered [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle)